# Model is not managed by any plugin

Tags: java, playframework, crud, playframework-1.x

I'm using Play!Framwork 1.2.5.

I'm trying to implement the CRUD in my project for my casses in models. I followed the steps described [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/guide7), but I'm getting the following error:

```
Model models.Media is not managed by any plugin
    at play.db.Model$Manager.factoryFor(Model.java:57)
    at controllers.CRUD$ObjectType.<init>(CRUD.java:215)
    at controllers.CRUD$ObjectType.get(CRUD.java:238)
    at controllers.CRUD$ObjectType$get.call(Unknown Source)
    at {module:crud}/app/views/tags/crud/types.tag.(line:4)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:247)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate$ExecutableTemplate.invokeTag(GroovyTemplate.java:401)
    at {module:crud}/conf/routes.(line:4)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:247)
    at play.templates.Template.render(Template.java:26)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.render(GroovyTemplate.java:202)
    at play.mvc.Router.parse(Router.java:162)
    at play.mvc.Router.parse(Router.java:190)
    at play.mvc.Router.parse(Router.java:164)
    at play.mvc.Router.load(Router.java:48)
    at play.mvc.Router.detectChanges(Router.java:219)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
```

here is the code of the class media:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import play.db.jpa.Model;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Media extends Model{
    @Id
    private String uuid;

    @OneToOne
    private Video video;
    @OneToOne
    private Picture picture;

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String id) {
        this.uuid = id;
    }


    public Video getVideo() {
        return video;
    }

    public void setVideo(Video video) {
        this.video = video;
    }

    public Picture getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }

    public void setPicture(Picture picture) {
        this.picture = picture;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Media))
            return false;
        Media media = (Media) obj;
        return media.getUuid().equals(this.uuid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code for `models.Media` class, please?

Comment: we need your import statements, I guess you are not extending the right Model class : do you have any Model class in your owm models package ?

Comment: no i dont have any other Model class: here are my import :import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import play.db.jpa.Model;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not used the right import statement.

Your import on `Media.java` model should be like below:

#### Media Model

```
import play.db.jpa.Model;

// should import javax.persistence.* package rather than org.hibernate.*
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Media extends Model {
   ....
}
```

If you marked field with relationship annotation (like `@OneToOne`), you should define the object as an `Entity`. So, your other model such as `Picture.java` or `Video.java` should import the same kind with `Media.java` like below:

#### Picture Model

```
import play.db.jpa.Model;

// don't forget to import javax.persistence.* package
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Picture extends Model {
   ...
}
```

#### Video Model

```
import play.db.jpa.Model;

// don't forget to import javax.persistence.* package too
import javax.persistence.Entity;


@Entity
public class Video extends Model {
   ...
}
```

I have tried this, and it works with me. Hope it helps to solve your problem.
Regards.